# How to match particular pattern with if condition

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

My text file :

```
Name: mak
Place: ynr
Age: 22
------------- 
Name: john
Place: kkr
Age: 21
------------- 
Name: mak
Place: knl
Age: 23
-------------
```

what I'm doing is :

```
open(FILE, "path to file") or die "";
$check="mak";
@arr=<FILE>
for(@arr)
{
    if ($_=/Name:\s(.*)/)
    {
        $a=$1;
        if($a eq $check)
        {
            print "matched name"
        }
        #now i want if "mak" is matched then after that it should match the age and store it one variable and then compare it with other matched age with same name
    }
}
```

I want to get the name first, if it matched as "mak" then I need to check age and compare age also.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? There are hundreds of examples of "matching things" in perl all over the internet. What's your code so far? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your code/refine your question. Do **not** post it in comments.

Comment: The source file looks similar to [YAML](http://yaml.org/). There is a [module](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML) that would do the parsing for you. (However, in YAML the horizontal bars must be three minuses `---` long)

Comment: In your code you use = instead =~

Comment: You can use `if (/Name:\s(.*)/)` to match on `$_`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file format can be described as follows:

- Multiple records are seperated from each other by a horizontal bar
- Each record has multiple name-value pairs, each on its own line

The Input record seperator `$/` can be set to arbitrary strings, so we can do

```
local $/ = "-------------\n";
```

Now, each readline operation will return one record. `chomp` will remove the seperator.

Getting the fields from a record is as simple as

```
my %fields = map split(/:\s*/, $_, 2), split /\n/, $record;
```

We can combine this to check a record at a time:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $check = shift @ARGV;

local $/ = "-------------\n";
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my %fields = map split(/:\s*/, $_, 2), split /\n/, $_;
  if ($fields{Name} eq $check) {
    # do something
  }
}
```

This would be invoked on the command line like `perl the-script.pl mak file.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to approach this, but here is one I like for its terseness:

```
use File::Slurp;
@records=split('---',read_file('file.txt'))
```

Now `$records[0]`, for example, contains:

```
Name: mak
Place: ynr
Age: 22
```

There will be "junk" entries in `@records` because the split pattern is not perfect, but that doesn't matter.  Now you can iterate over `@records` to find the one you need.

Comment: Hi I'm getting this error:
Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC

Comment: @Mak_Thareja You can substitute `read_file` with `do{open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die "Can't open file.txt: $!"; local $/; <$fh>}`, or you can install the `File::Slurp` module from CPAN. Run `cpan File::Slurp` on the command line, depending on your OS and kind of perl you have installed

Comment: Instead of iterating over `@records` "to find the one you need," why not just iterate over the original lines themselves (and there will not be any 'junk' entries in those)?

Comment: @kenosis I'm going to answer your question in the form of a question: why not take it one step further and iterate over all the _letters_ in the file?

Comment: @mak `File::Slurp` is a standard package you can get from CPAN, i.e. `cpan File::Slurp` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @rec;
while (<>) {
    push @rec, $1 if /^(?:Name|Place|Age):\s+(.+)/;
    next unless @rec == 3;

    print "@rec\n" if $rec[0] eq 'mak' and $rec[2] == 23;

    undef @rec;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter will redirect output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
mak knl 23
```

As file lines are read, the regex looks for lines beginning with Name, Age or Place and then captures all past the whitespace following the colon.  The captured value in `$1` is `push`ed onto `@rec`, and the next line is read `unless` the three record lines have been processed.  If element zero of `@rec` equals "mak" and element two equals 23, the record's values are printed.  Finally, `@rec` is `undef`ined, so it's ready for the next record.

Hope this helps!